# How to append the column values on particular criteria in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attaching the table structure with data

[image]

The column values without 0 value should be appended and updated inc column cyclenames. So, for row1 the cyclename should be "WIN,SPR,SUM,FAL" and row2 should be "SPR,FAL"

Can anyone help with the logic, I have implemented using if operator checking c1 to c12 and it's time consuming.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: What have your tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Did you tried using concat function ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `Replace`

```
SELECT Replace(CASE WHEN c1 <> '0' THEN c1 + ',' ELSE '' END
               + CASE WHEN c2 <> '0' THEN c2 + ',' ELSE '' END
               ...
               + CASE WHEN c12 <> '0' THEN c12 ELSE ',' END, ',,', '')
FROM   yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, I would do:

```
select stuff( ( (case when c1 <> '0' then ',' + c1 else '' end) +
                (case when c2 <> '0' then ',' + c2 else '' end) +
                . . .
                (case when c12 <> '0' then ',' + c12 else '' end),
              ), 1, 1, '')
from t;
```